# What is the proper way to get Arduino to "push" a button for me on a separate circuit?

Tags: computer-hardware

[image: buttons controlled by NMOSFET transistors]

So I built this little circuit in tinkerCAD and it does "work" but I feel like I'm not using these transistors correctly. Is there a more proper way to do what I'm trying to do here? I want the arduino to somehow create a short across the buttons using with as close to the voltage of the battery as possible.

Comment: Just by the way, that has to be one of the worst "fritzing" diagrams I have seen on this site. I hope you don't actually built the circuit as it is shown there.

Answer (score 2):

To get as close to the voltage of the battery as possible, consider using a single-pole, double-throw relay to reroute power straight from the battery. Here's a possible schematic where the Arduino controls the relay:
[image]

Just remember to protect the Arduino the same way you would a motor (or use a relay driver board). [Here is an Arduino tutorial](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/peterclement/working-with-relay-with-arduino-b777e6) for working with relays for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Another galvanically isolated switching method is the opto-isolator. These act somewhat like a cross between a relay and a transistor. Internally they are a LED shining at a light sensitive resistor and a maybe transistor to boost the switching current (depending on the model)

These can be used in a similar manner to the relay that @NullPointerException explained.